# Cleanest way to handle Union Types in Angular 16 Templates / Type inference?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, casting, typeerror

I'm working on an Angular 16 project where I use a reactive declarative approach.

Frequently, I have to deal with Observables that emit different types of data — either successful data or an error object. Both return types have their separate interfaces.

I usually define these as union types, but I find it cumbersome to handle these types within Angular templates.

Here an example:

```
interface DataSuccess {
  value: string;
}

interface DataError {
  error: boolean;
  message: string;
}

type DataOrError = DataSuccess | DataError | null;
```

In my component I have an Observable of this union type:

```
// COMPONENT
data$: Observable<DataOrError> = this.myService.getData();
```

In my Angular template, I want to display different content based on whether data$ emits a DataSuccess object or a DataError object. However, this results in TypeScript errors saying that error does not exist on type DataSuccess and value does not exist on type DataError.

```
// TEMPLATE
<div *ngIf="data$ | async as data">
  <!-- Throws TypeScript error -->
  <div *ngIf="data?.error">{{ data.message }}</div>
  <!-- Also throws TypeScript error -->
  <div *ngIf="!data?.error">{{ data.value }}</div>
</div>
```

What are the best practices for handling this kind of situation in Angular?
Is there a way to perform type-checking within Angular templates **without resorting to less type-safe methods (such as using the $any() type cast function) or moving the logic to the component file?**
Are there any Angular features or TypeScript features that I might be overlooking which could simplify this?

I saw a couple of similar questions on here, but they were old, had few answers, and the answers were not really satisfying. I wonder, if things have changed by now.

As an alternative, I thought about using a unified model, i.e. instead of having two different types and put it into a union, I would have something like this:

```
interface DataResponse {
value?: object;
error?: boolean;
message:? string;
}
```

This would resolve my template inference issue, however, I would loose some type safety. Would this be an advisable way to handle this or would this open the door for possible problems in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Here i created a stack blitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-9vxc5l?file=src%2Ftest.service.ts

In this i have created a new value called type in both of your response

```
 interface DataSuccess {
  type: ResponseType.success;
  value: string;
}

interface DataError {
  type: ResponseType.error;
  error: boolean;
  message: string;
}

enum ResponseType {
  success,
  error,
}
```

and assigned my result from the subscription to an object based on the type.
I think this would be an acceptable and also a clean way when you have multiple types for a single Observable.
This approach makes your code more type-safe.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer and also the StackBlitz example! I guess this approach would be quite similar to what I laid out in the end of my post with the ```error: boolean```. I could add it to all my interfaces, make it not optional and maybe call it isResponseError or isResponseSuccess. Would this be a sound/scalable approach? And what would be the benefit of the enum instead of a boolean?

Comment: Also, part of what makes this work is that you moved the logic to seperate between the types into the component (by having two extra variables which are conditionally presented). So the template does not know about the union type and does not throw the error. Additionaly you introduced a manual subscription/imperative code, which I try to avoid. I kind of hoped to hear about a solution which keeps the code declarative and reactive (not imperative) and deals with the union type inside of the template (without adding extra boilerplate code to the component). You know what I mean? Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Ok if you want a more scalable solution you can also create a BaseResponseInterface, add all your necessary values and make all your interfaces extend this base instead of adding a boolean to all of your interfaces.This would make it a lot more scalable . And by the way you mentioned that you preferred typesafety , that is the main benefit of using enum over boolean.
https://betterprogramming.pub/dont-use-boolean-arguments-use-enums-c7cd7ab1876a

Comment: Thanks for the info! I played around for quite a while and came up with this:
```interface DataResponse<T> { success: T | null; error: ErrorResponse | null }```
What do you think about that? Using Generics would allow to use the interface for all API calls and just exchange the T. Every response would have either the success or error property be null while the other holds the value. However, I'm not sure if this would be good pratice / scalable.

Comment: Yes that works too , you can try this to 
`interface BaseResponse {
  success: boolean;
  errors: Error[];
stackTrace : StackTrace[],
info:string
}`

Comment: Hey just saw your answer! Thanks again... I wonder, however, why you chose those properties? Especially the last two. Why is success: boolean ? I thought it be better to have an enum.